# What's wrong with the fonts

Tags: discussion, bug, design

In [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/90698/7885) and many, many more posts (I'm not sure, if this is SF&F specific or SE-wide?):

[image]

Google Chrome `42.0.2311.152 m`.

Comment: No idea if they're related, but I saw something similar in <sub> text: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257115/footnote-sub-text-collapsed-into-a-single-line-in-mobile-safari

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6823/unusual-character-placement-on-answer-screens?